# Not able to publish the app after integrating the adobe creative sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, adobecreativesdk

Ok, I implemented the adobe creative sdk to customise the image in my app but I am actually not able to publish the app to the app store. [image: see the screenshot of errors]

Let me tell you that I am getting these errors only when bitcode is enabled but when I tried to upload the build after disabling the bitcode, I was able to submit the app. I don't know if this one is duplicate question or not but I didn't find any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order to use bitcode, all your frameworks needs to have bitcode enabled as well. This is probably the issue you are running into since it is possible that the Adobe Creative SDK (or at least the version you are using) is not bitcode enabled. In such situations, the solution is to submit without bitcode enabled.